# Error (Steermouse manager 5.2.3) 130.0073

Tags: mouse, hardware, macos-mojave, logitech

I have the following error whenever I install steermouse and open the configuration panel:

```
Error (Steermouse manager 5.2.3) 130.0073
```

This happens with my G700s on Mac OS Mojave (10.14.2) macbook pro 2018. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the accessibility access SteerMouse needs. For some reason, the popup did not show when I installed the software. Enable it as follows:

Go to

`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility`

and check the **SteerMouse** checkbox. That should resolve the issue.